# Indefinite integral of a simple function

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$\int 2(1 + \tan^2 x)$

My work :

$2(1 + \tan^2(x) = 2 + 2\tan^2x$

$2x + \frac{2}{3}$ $\tan^3(x) \cdot \ln|sec(x)| + C$

The answer says no, after multiple tries :(

Comment: You seem to applying a chain rule for integrals. It doesn't work that way.  There is only a chain rule for derivatives, and doing it in reverse is called *integration by substitution.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\int2(1+\tan^2x)dx=2\int\sec^2x\ dx=2\tan x+K$$   as $$\frac{d(\tan x)}{dx}=\sec^2x$$

Comment: Thank you. *internet hug*
Gonna relearn my identities. :P

Comment: @MarsIsPrettyClose, Trigonometric identities are a must for integration, esp. for the indefinite ones.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sec^2 x-1=\tan^2 x$$

$$2\int \sec^2 x-1\,\mathrm{d}x+2\int \mathrm{d}x=2\int \sec^2 x\,\mathrm{d}x=2\tan x+c$$

Comment: Thank you. *internet hug*
Gonna relearn my identities. :P

Comment: @MarsIsPrettyClose lol at *internet hug*

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake here was in thinking that

$$\int(\tan x)^2 dx = \frac{(\tan x)^3}{3} + C\tag{wrong!}$$

but **this is not correct**. The rule that

$$\int x^a dx = \frac{x^{a+1}}{a+1} + C$$

only works when $x$ is *literally* the same variable that appears in $dx$.

This does actually allow you to write things like

$$\int (\tan x)^a d(\tan x) = \frac{(\tan x)^{a+1}}{a+1} + C$$

but you have to make sure you understand what $d(\tan x)$ means, and you have to be careful because this doesn't work if the thing in the differential (here $\tan x$) is not sufficiently "well-behaved" throughout the region of integration.